# Weird spacing on mobile web Achievement drop-down tab

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, mobile-web

There is some weird spacing on the mobile web site:

[image]

Additionally, the main font color has changed from black to yellow:

[image]

Can this be fixed please?

Comment: Thanks for reporting that. we've just pushed some bigger changes to mobile code and apparently there are some smaller issues now. I will work on those two you've just reported and push fixes asap. Thanks again!

Comment: You beat me to it. Confirming for Chromium (stock browser) on s4.

Comment: @pawel, also the red notification icon. It's overlapping the no notification icon.

Comment: @cde will take a look at that as well, thanks!

Comment: Fixes are already in repo waiting for build.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, now both of those issues should be fixed on production. Thanks for reporting!

Comment: Sorry to unaccept, but the bug is back now since the fixes are reverted.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I can't see those issues anymore.. What are you refering to?

Comment: This bug is causes by a long post name as far as I remember and was fixed by setting the viewport. Since the latter is gone, this bug is back again.

Comment: @PatrickHofman can you please share a screenshot + device / os version info?

Comment: Sorry, never mind. I accidentally mixed up with another one which does cause sizing issues with the post name and the archievements dialog on mobile. Will try to find that one.