# Notification graphic off on mobile version

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, mobile-web, top-bar

The red inbox notification is slightly off center to me. On the left side of the red "1" in the below image you can see parts of the empty inbox symbol beneath.

[image: Notification off center]

Here is a dump of my version readings:

> Google Chrome  51.0.2704.81 (Official Build) (32-bit)
>   Revision    211d45a5b74b06d12bb016f3c4d54095faf2646f-refs/branch-heads/2704@{#696}
>   OS  Android 5.1.1; Nexus 4 Build/LMY48T

Comment: I commented http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283063/weird-spacing-on-mobile-web-achievement-drop-down-tab#comment917560_283063 and @pawel had previously acknowledge it

Comment: @cde I saw that question, but since there were no immediate overlap, I didn't read the comments beneath.

Comment: Fix is already in repo waiting for build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for reporting this. We've just fixed it and it should be live :)

Comment: According to the notification I got from this answer, it seems fixed.